# How to create DB tables for custom objects in Intershop7.9

Tags: database, orm, intershop

We are trying to insert tables for custom objects in Intershop database. We are creating the ORM model through EDL files and generating the code with "Intershop Code generator for versions 7.2 and later", however there is no option to generate DDL schema for tables, as it was possible in Enfinity Studio 6.4.

[Code generator screenshot - Intershop 7 Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vnw1.png)

On the Intershop support site there is a description on how to execute only the DDL preparers during the dbinit, but only for version 7.10 which is in beta phase.

Is it possible to init only the custom DB tables in Intershop 7.9 or to generate the DDL schema which can be executed on the DB directly? We do not want to run the whole dbinit process each time we need to create a new custom object in the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 7.x you don't need to generate the DDL for creating the tables. That is now handled by the prepares. You can use these dbmigration prepares to create the tables for you.

```
Class1 = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbmigrate.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer

Class2 = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbmigrate.preparer.database.DatabaseIndexesPreparer \
         resources/custom_cartridge/dbinit/scripts/1.0.0.0/dbindex.ddl

Class3 = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbmigrate.preparer.database.DatabaseConstraintsPreparer \
         resources/custom_cartridge/dbinit/scripts/1.0.0.0/dbconstraints.ddl
```

As you can see above you still get the DDL for the constraints and indexes

Comment: Is it possible to execute those single preparers without running the whole dbinit process?

Comment: yes, if u run dbmigrate those prepares will only run once, create the tables and then never again. Always run dbmigrate on production after the initial dbinit.